# Ruby stopping search at first array element

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to use a drop down which will filter a table based on whether or not a premises contains a specific species. Some premises have multiple species. If I am attempting to find all premises with the species 'Horse' it will only find ones where horse is first in the array. If the specific element is not first in the array it is not filtered and shown. Here is the query used below.

```
@species = params[:species].presence
@default_species = @species.blank? ? 'All Species' : Species.find_cached_by_short_name(@species)&.long_name || @species

@prems = StatevetPrem.unmatched.search(@search, @page, @lines_per_page, { order: @sort })
@prems = @prems.where(state: @state) if @state

if @species
  prem_ids = StatevetDoc.
               unmatched.
               select(:holdings_match).
               where(default_species: @species).
               limit(@lines_per_page).
               collect { |doc| doc.holdings_match.values }.
               flatten.
               uniq[0,999]
  @prems = @prems.where(id: prem_ids)
end
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Apologies, how do I alter the query to look past the first element in the array.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the select method instead of the collect method in your query.

Comment: When using select this returns no results.